# LINQ to SQL compatibility between different version of SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, compatibility

I have created my DataClasses by connecting to a **SQL Server 2005** database.  Do I need to recompile if my application is to connect to a **SQL Server 2000** database?

SQL Server 2000 doesn't support the ROW_NUMBER() function.  I'm using Skip() and Take() methods of LINQ to SQL to page through my records.  Will LINQ to SQL properly generate the correct SQL query eventhough it was compiled to connect to a newer version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL is chosen based on the server ***at runtime***. The IDE-generated code (C# etc) is not version-specific. No, you don't have to do anything to re-target a different DB version.

However, some code ***will fail*** against SQL2000 if you try that. It is simply not possible (at least, conveniently or sanely) to do some of the skip/take/etc without reasonable DB support. Some things it can do... Some things it can't. You will need to integration-test your app for that platform.

Comment: Alternatively, you could stop using unsupported versions of SQL Server. See http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=2852